# Is it possible to have } horizontally in LaTex?

Tags: equations, symbols, amsmath

Is it possible to have } horizontally in LaTex?

I can write:

`({u_1}{e_1} + {u_2}{e_2}`

But how to put the `}` horizontally?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\underbrace{({u_1}{e_1} + {u_2}{e_2})}_{\textrm{Scalar $C_{ue}$}}$
\end{document}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Wowo, thanks, it works. Can I put as equation? `\begin{equation}
    \underbrace{({u_1}{e_1} + {u_2}{e_2})}_{\textrm{Scalar C_{ue}}}
\end{equation}`?

Comment: Yes, it can be used in both text style and display style equations.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks. Can you write an answer if can? I tried using in `equation`, but not works,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\underbrace` works on the same way in an inline math as well as in a displayed math environment. However, in both cases, you should write math expression correctly in the both cases (what you not do in your comment)

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document} 

$\underbrace{(u_1 e_1 + u_2 e_2)}_{\textrm{Scalar $C_{ue}$}}$ 

\begin{equation} 
\underbrace{(u_1e_1 + u_2e_2)}_{\textrm{Scalar $C_{ue}$}} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. I did not know that `$$` can work inside an `equation`. That is new to me

Comment: @aan, i my answers is not used `$$` delimiters, but `$`. Note: `\textrm{<content>}` put `<content>` in text mode, so if you have inside it math expression as is `C_{ue}` you need to write in math mode, i.e.: write is as showed in in bot examples in answer.

Comment: Isn't that literally [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542141/is-it-possible-to-have-horizontally-in-latex#comment1369361_542141)?

Answer (score 0):

With tikz thanks to the cat @SchrodingersCat

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm] 
 \draw (-1,0) -- (4,0); 
 \path foreach \X/\Y/\Z  in  
  {0/a_0/a_1, pi/b_0/, {pi/2}/b_1/b_2,{pi/4}/a_2/a_2} 
     { (\X,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=0.5mm, 
        label=above:{$\Y$},label=below:{$\Z$},alias=\Z] (\Y) {}}; 
 \begin{scope}[thick,decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt}] 
  \draw[decorate]   (current bounding box.north) coordinate (aux) 
    (a_2|-aux) -- node[above=1ex]{$I_2$} (b_1|-aux); 
  \draw[decorate]   (current bounding box.south) coordinate (aux) 
    (b_1|-aux) -- node[below=1ex]{$I_1$} (a_0|-aux); 
  \draw[decorate]   (current bounding box.south) coordinate (aux) 
    (b_0|-aux) -- node[below=1ex]{$I_0$} (a_0|-aux); 
 \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```